# Java | How Count all methods with Reflection & RTTI?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, numbers, rtti

In our uni project we were asked to build a project in which we should also provide an info class in which we should insert all the info like total  number of lines of code, number of methods (in the whole project).
We were asked to provide the complete number of methods, to compute with Reflection & RTTI, and obviously with no use of external libraries.

How shall I do?

Comment: Why not use a static analisys tool like Sonar? EDIT: I missed that this was homework. You can disregard this comment.

Comment: Well, you start by writing some code. I guess the idea of a university project is ... that you **learn** how to do that by **trying** it yourself. So, the best thing you can get here is a hint like: use javas file system capabilities to fetch a list of all class files from disk. Then use java reflection mechanisms to collect the statistics you need.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest approach you can use is,

1. Create a `class` to store the info you need ( number of methods,lines or whatever) - use setters/getters.
2. Use a `static block` in all your application classes, to calculate the methods, lines etc for each class & update it to info class.
3. I hope at a given instant it can give you the `info about the loaded number of methods/code`.

As @Jägermeister rightly said, the aim of this project is to try-out things yourself. So I gave some insights - `which you can follow & try out yourself.`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I came to a solution, thank you all.

Here's the code:

```
private int getNumMethods() {
    java.io.File src = new java.io.File("src/APManager2016");
    int result = 0;
    if (src.isDirectory()) {
        String[] list = src.list((java.io.File dir, String name) -> name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java"));
        try {
            for (String x : list) {
                Class<?> c = Class.forName("APManager2016." + x.replace(".java", ""));
                result += c.getDeclaredMethods().length;

            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            result = 0;
        }
    }
    if (result == 0)
    {
        result = 111;
    }
    return result;

}
```